# In Kuberentes can we create a network policy to restrict unix socket creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

Going through [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) doc, was wondering if there is a way to restrict unix socket creation using Kubernetes Network policies.

Comment: Kubernetes network policies can’t restrict unix socket creation, they can only be useful for managing the traffic flow in between the pods. If you want to restrict new unix sockets from getting created you need to configure the SElinux parameter in the security context field of the kubernetes manifest file. This feature is only available in the recent releases of kubernetes 1.25 and above. Follow this [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#assign-selinux-labels-to-a-container) for more information

Comment: for the better visibility of the community I'm posting the same as a response, revert back if you need any additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kubernetes network policies** can’t restrict **unix socket** creation, they can only be useful for managing the traffic flow in between the pods. If you want to restrict new unix sockets from getting created you need to configure the **SElinux parameter** in the **security context** field of the kubernetes manifest file. This feature is only available in the recent releases of ***kubernetes 1.25*** and above. Follow this [**official documentation**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#assign-selinux-labels-to-a-container) for more information